# How to register for Actions while backgrounded

Tags: ios, xcode, background, task, facetime

I've seen for example the Garage Band Application and the FaceTime Application running/recording, while using other apps (see photo) and wondered how to register my current project for coloring the statusbar (so running in the background)

Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: The subject of your question contradicts your actual question. Please update one of them so they match.